# Как определить Webhook discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, discord.py

Я запрашиваю у пользователя ввести URL Webhook'а, а мне необходимо проверить, является ли эта ссылка вебхуком или это неправильная ссылка. Это всё реализовывается в команде телеграм бота на aiogram. Есть также библиотека disnake, я же знаю, что там есть типы, но не нашёл про Webhook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhook изначально добавлялся в Discord как упрощенный инструмент для передачи сообщений.
Webhook не требует специальной авторизации, так как уже носят в себе токен.
Таким образом, никаких специальных библиотек для обработки webhook'ов не нужно.

1. Проверьте ссылку - действительно ли эта ссылка ведёт на Discord? В противном случае, ваш бот Telegram может отправлять запросы на сторонние сайты, если следующий пункт пройдёт проверку.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

ALLOWED_DISCORD_DOMAINS = [
    "discord.com",
    "canary.discord.com",
    "ptb.discord.com",
    "discordapp.com",
    "canary.discordapp.com",
    "ptb.discordapp.com"
] 
# canary и ptb - публичные тестовые сборки
# discordapp.com - устаревший, но теоретически, еще используемый домен Discord


url: str = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/{ID}/{TOKEN}"
...
if not urlparse(url).netloc in ALLOWED_DISCORD_DOMAINS:
   return "FAIL" # raise Exception, etc
```

2. Задайте [GET-запрос полученному адресу](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#get-webhook-with-token), он должен вернуть [Webhook-объект](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#webhook-object) в JSON.

```py
async with aiohttp.Session() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            return f"Unable to send a request to that webhook. Discord returns {response.status} ({response.reason})" # 400 (Bad Request) / 404 (Not Found) / 418 (I'm teapot)
        webhook = await response.json()
        if not webhook.get("type") == 1:
            return "Wrong webhook type. Only manually channel-generated webhooks are supported"
        if not webhook.get("id") or not webhook.get("token"):
            return "Provided webhook missing ID or token. Unable to interact with it"
```